# How to import a binary data generated by Fortran?

Tags: import, binary, fortran

I have a unformatted binary data file generated by gfortran. However, when the binary data is imported by Mathematica, a correct result is not obtained.

This is my fortran code:

```
  Module Output
    interface export
      module procedure export_IMA1
    end interface

    contains
    subroutine export_IMA1(filename, ma)
        character(*), INTENT(IN)::filename
        integer, intent(in)::ma(:)
        integer*1::I
        open(unit=55,file=filename//".dat", status="replace",&
             Access="stream")
        write(55) ma
        close(55)
    end subroutine export_IMA1
   end module Output

    Program Test
    use output
    implicit none
    integer::c(4)=[1,2,3,4]
    call export("c",c)
    end program
```

The fortran is simplified, such a code just stores the integer array c=[1,2,3,4] in a stream style. The Mathematica code is

```
Block[{
       filename3 = "Code/c.dat", 
       l}, 
  SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
  str = OpenRead[filename3, BinaryFormat -> True];
  l = BinaryReadList[str, "Integer32", 4, ByteOrdering -> $ByteOrdering];
  Close[filename3];
]
```

and the result l=1 not l=[1,2,3,4]. How do you correctly import the binary data (stream) generated by the Fortran code into Mathematica?

I show c.dat (c=[1,2,3,4]) in vim after hexdump as following:

[image]

and the text form is https://pastebin.com/x5m0dXsK

Comment: Can you explain the format of the data for those of us who are not very familiar with Fortran?  A quick google search seems to tell me that `integer*1` means 8-bit integers in Fortran, but you're trying to read 32-bit ones in Mathematica.

Comment: HI Szabolcs, Type "integer*1": a 8-bit integer number and Type "integer" means that 4*8-bit integer number. Type "Real": 8*8-bit real number. Type "Complex": 8*8-bit complex number (4*8-bit for real part and 4*8bit for imaginary part)

Comment: Could you give an example of the data - the first few lines, perhaps?

Comment: Please post the data as text rather than as an image.

Comment: I present the c.dat generated by fortran, and it is shown in the figure after hexdump.

Comment: As Carl mentioned, the image is no good to us. Please share the file instead. For instance, you should be able to use e.g. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or similar services.

Comment: The c.dat records c=[1,2,3,4] and the text shows "Ä?Ä?@Ä?" which is a binary form. I just transformed it into a hex form.

Comment: OK let's try a different tackle. You wrote the fortran code / have some fortran experience, I assume; I unfortunately have none. So perhaps you could **describe** what the fortran code outputs, for us to try and help you import it.

Comment: Thanks. I will simplify my fortran code, so that the fortran code will just save an integer array c=[1,2,3,4] in a stream style.

Comment: I used the provided fortran code to recreate the file [c.dat](https://filebin.net/fv5vp4cdv3um373b).  This imports in Mathematica with no issue for me with `BinaryReadList[str, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1]`

Comment: Hi gays! Thanks for your help! I figure out what my problem is.  I got l=1 due to evaluating it in a new cell. If  adding a sentence "print[l];"  in the Module. I will get the correct result.

Comment: You don't need `Print`, just remove `l` from the `{filename3 = "Code/c.dat", 
       l}` of `Block`.

Comment: @Szabolcs : integer*1 is non-portable (not part of Fortran standard), so depending on the Compiler and platform, it could mean any integer kind in Fortran.

Comment: @finalboss You may want to ask your question on StackOverflow with Fortran tag on the question.